# comparing five integers with if , else if statement

Tags: c++

I need to compare five integers and find the biggest and smallest. I need to solve it by only using if and else statements, I can't use arrays or specific functions that find the max, min input.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, biggest,smallest;
n1=biggest;


cout << "Enter the five numbers: ";

cin >> n1 >> n2 >> n3 >> n4 >> n5 ;

if ((n2>=n1) && (n2>=n3) && (n2>=n4) && (n2>=n5)) {
    n2 = biggest;
}
else if ((n3>=n4) && (n3>=n5)) {
    n3 = biggest ;
}
else if (n4>=n5) {
    n4 = biggest ;
}
else {
    n5 = biggest ;
}

cout << biggest ;
```

Why does this output 0 instead of the biggest number?

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your conditions are not sufficient

Comment: So `n1` can never be biggest?

Comment: You never assign a value to `biggest`. Basically, this overwrites a piece of your input any time a test passes

Comment: Among other things, you should be assigning a value to biggest, e.g., `biggest = n2`, rather than `n2 = biggest`

Comment: @deviantfan the problem is that it returns 0 instead of returning the biggest number

Comment: I know but how could i be while there are these kind of people who did not reading question and wrote comments...I am sorry but people should be more careful while they are reading the question, the should read well

Comment: @fatih_turkey You've already had an answer to that: you never assigned a value to biggest. That's trivial. The rest of your program is wrong, and you have several suggestions that answer that, but you've downvoted all of them.

Comment: The inaccurate comment (cout does not return 0, it may output 0 or who knows what or nothing at all) at the end of your code does not constitute a question. Try something like, "Why does this output 0 instead of the biggest number?"

Comment: you are paroniac dude, so far i have never downvoted anybody, not just for this question

Comment: There, your question now has a question. You're welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :

```
int main ()
{
int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, biggest,smallest;
cout << "Enter the five numbers: ";

cin >> n1 >> n2 >> n3 >> n4 >> n5 ;

smallest=biggest=n1;
if(n2>biggest){
    biggest=n2;
}
if(n2<smallest){
      smallest=n2;
}
if(n3>biggest){
   biggest=n3;
}
if(n3<smallest){
      smallest=n3;
}
if(n4>biggest){
    biggest=n4;
}
if(n4<smallest){
      smallest=n4;
}
if(n5>biggest){
     biggest=n5;
}
if(n5<smallest){
      smallest=n5;
}

cout<<smallest<<"\t"<<biggest;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've never heard of loops and arrays?

Comment: @JamesKanze yes i heard a lot but they need using `if` no array, no function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this under the limitations described, it's going to be something like (pseudocode):

```
smallest = n1
if n1 <= n2 and n1 <= n3 and n1 <= n4 and n1 <= n5
  smallest = n1
else if n2 <= n3 and n2 <= n4 and...
  smallest = n2
 ...
```

then the same again in reverse for biggest. Pure drudgery.

Comment: For input `2 1 1 1 1` this will calculate `smallest == 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it simply. Sure there's smarter and faster ways, but this one works...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

inline void checkBiggestAndSmallest( int& smallest, int& biggest, int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5 )
{
    if ( n1 >= n2 && n1 >= n3 && n1 >= n4 && n1 >= n5 )
        biggest = n1;

    if ( n1 <= n2 && n1 <= n3 && n1 <= n4 && n1 <= n5 )
        smallest = n1;
}

inline void findBiggestAndSmallest( int& smallest, int& biggest, int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5 )
{
    checkBiggestAndSmallest( smallest, biggest, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5 );
    checkBiggestAndSmallest( smallest, biggest, n2, n3, n4, n5, n1 );
    checkBiggestAndSmallest( smallest, biggest, n3, n4, n5, n1, n2 );
    checkBiggestAndSmallest( smallest, biggest, n4, n5, n1, n2, n3 );
    checkBiggestAndSmallest( smallest, biggest, n5, n1, n2, n3, n4 );
}

int main()
{
    int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, biggest = 0, smallest = 0;

    cout << "Enter the five numbers: ";
    cin >> n1 >> n2 >> n3 >> n4 >> n5 ;

    findBiggestAndSmallest( smallest, biggest, n5, n1, n2, n3, n4 );

    cout << "Smallest : " << smallest;
    cout << "Biggest : " << biggest;
}
```

Comment: Agreed. But of course, the people who do it are not likely to have anything to say, so it's probably no loss.

Comment: @Jon Kiparsky If you agree, would you vote up to compensate? ;-)

Comment: @fatih_turkey: Are you kiding....there is NO QUESTION in your post....my code does what you asked, did not use min, max. If you're not allowed to use fonctions, you need to mention it! And you can also copy/paste the function code to the place where functions are invoked to remove the function calls.....think you can manage to do that?

Comment: @jpo38 even though you did not understand cout returns 0 part, you should understand the part with  only if, else if statement. you did not even read the title

Comment: @fatih_turkey: To say you need to solve the problem with only if else if statement is ambiguous. Your own solution uses more things than if and else statements. It uses comparison operators, logical operators, assignment operators, calls to input and output functions, and declarations.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: you're faster than me...thanks for your support ;-).

Comment: @fatih_turkey: sorry for having tried to help...this kind of question you asked should simply be flagged and deleted by moderators (like the comment where you said users working or your question were "idiots"...)

Comment: okey i am sorry, i was wrong,  but you dude, you have should not answer with some functions while i indicated that if , else if statement.

Comment: And you're still wrong. A "function" is not a "statement". So when you say "use only if, else statements" you don't say "don't use functions".

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a variable x (which is uninitialized, and has no cin value), but you want to set it equal to another variable, let's call it a (which is uninitialized and has a cin value).

You cannot say a = x.

it is not the same thing as x = a. Which is why you are having output problems.

```
//assume all variables and libraries are declared

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    biggest = n1;

    if (n1 < n2)
        biggest = n2;

    if (n2 < n3)
        biggest = n3;

    if (n3 < n4)
        biggest = n4;

    if (n4 < n5)
        biggest = n5;

    cout << "The biggest input value is " << biggest << ".\n";
```

And remember, a = x, is not the same as x = a.

one more tip, if you have an if statement that only applies to the following line after it, like so:
    if (x != 2)
        cout << "x doesn't equal 2.";
then you don't need to put it inside a block using {}

However, if you have a multiple line if statement (or any other statement, including loops)
then it is necessary, or the program will execute the if statement, the line after it, and treat the rest of the lines proceeding it as regular code, and execute it even if the parameters aren't met.

like so:
    if (x != 2)
        cout << "x doesn't equal 2.";
        return 0;

only in the case above will you need the block.

I hope that helps!

~Tamra

Comment: thank you for informing me, i changed n1>biggest part, and the program returned me the code that explains why it quit and i learned something from your comment,

Comment: You're very welcome. I don't like it when people don't actually read and just focus on the code. It's better to know what's wrong, that's what learning about c++ is! Figuring out why it does what it does and how to fix it. I'm glad that I have helped you learn something. Good luck with your program!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following:

```
std::pair<int, int> get_min_max(int n1, int n2)
{
    if (n1 < n2) {
        return {n1, n2};
    } else {
        return {n2, n1};
    }
}

std::pair<int, int> get_min_max(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5)
{
    auto p1 = get_min_max(n1, n2);
    auto p2 = get_min_max(n3, n4);
    auto mini = get_min_max(p1.first, p2.first).first;
    auto maxi = get_min_max(p1.second, p2.second).second;
    if (n5 < mini) {
        return {n5, maxi};
    } else if (maxi < n5) {
        return {mini, n5};
    } else {
        return {mini, maxi};
    }
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/FNBUfm)

Answer (score 0):

a variadic could help you with this:

```
template<typename T>
T Max( T a ) { return a; }

template<typename T,typename ...Ts>
T Max( T a, T b, Ts... ts)
{
    if(a>b) return Max(a,ts...);
    else    return Max(b,ts...);
}
```

then you could use it like:

```
biggest = Max( n1, n2, n3, n4, n5 );
```

`Max` work for any number of arguments (except none)